# PHP MYSQL query not receiving data from $_POST for update

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table

I am trying to call and update a table row in a database using certain criteria. Currently I have the table load the data in textboxes and automatically assign NAMES of all the textboxes so that I can use them later to update.

**Code to display**

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$check=$_POST["scenario1"];
$qwert="SELECT * FROM izprashtane WHERE Сценарий='$check'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$qwert);
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM izprashtane";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo "<table width=650 border=1>\n";
$counter=0;
while ($get_info = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<td>" . $row['Field'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    $counter=0;
    foreach ($get_info as $field){
        $counter += 1;
        echo "\t<td><input type='text' name='$counter' value='$field'></td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
$conn->close();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="datacizprashtane.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="Промяна" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This loads the table row in a table with editable textboxes and it assigns names from 0-to however I need. Then I got the code to update the table. It is just experimental so I got only 2 textboxes and I'll add the rest once I get it going.

**Code to update**

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "UPDATE izprashtane SET НаселеноМясто='$_POST[2]',Тримесичие='$_POST[3]' WHERE Сценарий='$_POST[6]'";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

$conn->close();
```

At this point it gives me:

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�аселеноМясто='',Тримес' at line 1.

I have tried to use `'".$_POST[3]."'` but then it doesn't even give me the error. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Set the charset before running that query `$conn ->set_charset("utf8")`

Comment: `$_POST` is an associative array, not a numeric array, so you can't access them like `$_POST[3]`, `$_POST[6]` etc.

Comment: Well the Charset allowed the page to get me Record updated successfully but actually nothing is updated... even though my default encoding of the document was UTF8

Comment: @RajdeepPaul He dynamically assigns numerical values to the input names, check what the $counter variable does in the first code.

Comment: While you are at it, I would also introduce some input filtering. Eg 
$check=$_POST["scenario1"], replace with $check = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'scenario1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that the `<input...>` fields in your HTML are not inside a `<form....`> tag.

If fields are not placed inside a `<form>` they are not sent when the submit button is pressed. In fact they are not even inside the page `<body>`

Currently only the submit button is inside your `<form>` tag, which is why the submit is being actioned but no data is being passed and you are not checking the fields actually exist before using them.

Comment: The inputs are going to be named 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8..... which is what is going to be in the `$_POST` array. He should be using quotes like `$_POST['2']` to access them though. I think he was having issues with double quotes hence why he decided to post it without the quotes.

Comment: You must have just updated it as I posted the comment, all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Give the following a go with prepared statements:

```
$sql = "UPDATE izprashtane SET НаселеноМясто=?,Тримесичие=? WHERE Сценарий=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $_POST['2'], $_POST['3'], $_POST['6']);
mysqli_execute($stmt);
```

Also, your code is a bit of a mess, make sure to escape strings using prepared statements or `mysqli_escape_string` to avoid SQL Injections.

EDIT:
Also, add

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

After the second database connection while also making sure that your inputs are all in your form.

Comment: Actually we are both wrong as I just remembered that missing the quotes when referencing an assoc array in a string like that is in fact valid. So I will delete my answer

Comment: Ahh, I see. However, he will be starting his names at 1 rather than 0, so I'm not sure if he really wants to be using this method to access the input values. I'll edit this and wait for his reply.

Comment: No I think this is very dodgy also but I have seen the probeom now, writing another answer now

Comment: <td><input type='text' name='1' value='265'></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='2' value='Перник склад'></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='3' value='4-то'></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='4' value='буркани с халва'></td>
 <td><input type='text' name='5' value='12,12,15'></td> This is how the page source is after i display the table row... just a small part of it as you can see the textboxes have valid names.

Comment: You might also want to put all of the inputs in the form e.g. The form starting before your inputs.

Comment: Additionally, add `mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");` on that page as well.

Comment: Ah @Matt you spotted that form issue to

Comment: I have added it. I will try to put the form tags in the page which generates the table with echoes but i dont think it will have any effect cause the problem is not displaying them but accessing them or something ... will try it as quick as i can

Comment: Yes it works i moved the input fields with echoes in the PHP code and it worked with the query format of $sql = "UPDATE izprashtane SET НаселеноМясто='$_POST[2]',Тримесичие='$_POST[3]' WHERE Сценарий='$_POST[6]'";. SO TO SUM UP THE QUERY AND EVERYTHING WAS CORRECT ONLY PROBLEM WAS THAT INPUT FIELDS WERE NOT IN A FORM ATTRIBUTE. Thank you guys for your time and wisdom.

Comment: Please remember to escape strings before inserting them into an SQL query. Your whole database could be compromised and all of your user data stolen if you do not escape user input. Please just take a look into it.

Comment: If we assume that no one else will see the page, besides the intended ppl should i still waste time into escaping and stuff and how would you suggest I do that ?

Comment: I'll put it this way, if I decided to visit your website with a malicious intent, I could steal everything, gain access to your site and destroy all of your files within a couple of minutes with my eyes closed. I would take a look at https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ and honestly, it's as easy as just using `$value = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $value);` and using `(int)$value` for numbers. It will save you big time down the line.

Answer (score 0):

you must place all the form fields in between form tags(`<form>...</form>`)
ex:

```
<form action="datacizprashtane.php" method="POST">
<?php
//write your php code here.
?>
<input type="submit" value="Промяна" >
</form>
```

i hope it will help you...